# Makefile string substitution using variable

Tags: makefile, string-substitution

I want to remove the root directory of a targeted path in a Makefile.

Let say the target is like

```
OUTPUT = output
PATH = $(OUTPUT)/a.txt
```

Later when building the target, this works

```
echo $(@:output/%=%)
>>> a.txt
```

But not if I use the var $OUTPUT instead of the string:

```
echo $(@:$(OUTPUT)/%=%)
>>> output/a.txt
```

Comment: Both work for me.

Comment: The makefile section you call "the target is like" is not a target.  Those are variable assignments.  You don't actually show the target; please show the entire makefile rule in question, not just a part of the recipe.  An SSCCE http://sscce.org/ would be best.